# How do I write a valid Vector Loki Configuration

Tags: docker-compose, grafana-loki

I'm trying to write a `vector.toml` file for a loki sink but keep getting this error

> ERROR vector::topology: Configuration error. error=Sink "loki": invalid format

If I leave out the labels block it complains that the section is required as indicated in the documentation.

Here is my `vector.toml`

```
# Set global options
data_dir = "/var/lib/vector"

# Vector's API (disabled by default)
# Enable and try it out with the `vector top` command
[api]
enabled = false
# address = ":8686"

[sources.docker]
type = "docker_logs"
docker_host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

[sinks.loki]
type = "loki"
inputs = [ "docker" ] 
endpoint = "loki:3100" 
compression = "none"

  [sinks.loki.labels]
  forwarder = "vector"
  event = "{{ event_field }}"
  key = "value"
  "\"{{ event_field }}\"" = "{{ another_event_field }}"

  [sinks.loki.encoding]
  codec = "json"
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  appnet:
    external: true

services:
  vector:
    image: timberio/vector:nightly-debian
    container_name: vector
    hostname: vector
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - DOCKER_HOST="unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    ports:
      - '8383:8383'
    volumes:
      - ./vector.toml:/etc/vector/vector.toml:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - appnet
```

edit: I made the changes suggested below but got these errors:

> 2022-06-07T09:40:00.995020Z ERROR vector::topology::builder:
> msg="Healthcheck: Failed Reason." error=A non-successful status
> returned: 503 Service Unavailable component_kind="sink"
> component_type="loki" component_id=loki component_name=loki
> 2022-06-07T09:46:47.105846Z  WARN sink{component_kind="sink"
> component_id=loki component_type=loki
> component_name=loki}:request{request_id=83}:
> vector::sinks::util::retries: Retrying after error. error=Server
> responded with an error: 500 Internal Server Error
> 2022-06-07T09:46:47.225056Z  INFO
> vector::internal_events::docker_logs: Stopped watching for container
> logs.
> container_id=721d72a4bc751721703828ff79e275e357f490445de51bc70781a5f0bbdd0a01
> 2022-06-07T09:46:48.111371Z ERROR sink{component_kind="sink"
> component_id=loki component_type=loki
> component_name=loki}:request{request_id=83}:http:
> vector::internal_events::http_client: HTTP error. error=error trying
> to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)
> error_type="request_failed" stage="processing"
> 2022-06-07T09:46:48.111559Z  WARN sink{component_kind="sink"
> component_id=loki component_type=loki
> component_name=loki}:request{request_id=83}:
> vector::sinks::util::retries: Retrying after error. error=Failed to
> make HTTP(S) request: Failed to make HTTP(S) request: error trying to
> connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)

Here is my loki docker-compose.yml config:

```
version: '2.4'

networks:
  appnet:
    external: true

volumes:
  loki_data:

services:
  loki:
    container_name: loki
    hostname: loki
    image: grafana/loki:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - appnet
    ports:
      - 3100:3100
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/localtime
        target: /etc/localtime
      - type: volume
        source: loki_data
        target: /data
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/s3-loki-bolt-conf.yml
        target: /etc/loki/local-config.yaml
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
    mem_limit: 3g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it found loki: somewhere it was not expecting it. Having a look at your TOML and the Vector.dev reference (https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/sinks/loki/),under [sinks.loki] I would try changing your endpoint from

`endpoint = "loki:3100"`

to:

`endpoint = "http://loki:3100"`

Comment: That was an improvement but produced connection refused errors. Docker ps reports loki is running.

Comment: Can you access into the Loki container to check logs / status of the Loki application/service? Does your Loki configuration instruct Loki to listen on 3100?

Comment: How do I do that? Doesn't loki listen on :3100 by default? I only want to monitor containers so I don't want to expose ports on the docker host and I don't want to use the docker loki plugin.